# <lightning:input> tag in Lightning do not have keyup attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am facing the issue with  :

I am using a lookup with lightning: input. When the user clicks enter search text in this input field. New component opens up showing related search records.

Now to close search window, I have a cross button in front of the field.

The user wants that on clicking anywhere outside search result component/box. This component should get closed. Now I am unable to find any workaround of attribute keyUp which we use in ui:input. Any idea how to achieve that.

[image]

Comment: have you tried wrapping your input in a div tag with the keyup attribute? I recall lightning:input not fully supporting this, hence the wrapping in a div (or any other html tag that supports onkeyup

Comment: It sounds like you actually want onblur, not onkeyup? That will tell you when they've clicked outside of the lightning:input

Comment: Thanks for suggestions!
but the issue is as you can see this is a Multi check box. So when I click on a single checkbox, onblur gets called and dropdown goes off.

I want, it should not go off when clicked within this component. it should go when clicked outside only.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the keyup to and input field, you just have to specify UpdateOn so that the change event triggers on keyup

```
<ui:inputText aura:id="searchInput" 
    label="Search" 
    keyup="{!c.performSearch}" 
    updateOn="keyup" />
```

[Source](http://peterknolle.com/lightning-input-component-value-binding/)

Edit: I'm pretty sure this will work on a lightning:input as well, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: I don't see `updateOn` documented in e.g. [lightning:input (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm).

Comment: unfortunately, the attribute is not available on lightning: input